# How can I update the domain name of all my bookmarks for a site?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, domain-name

I have a lot of bookmarks for a site that is changing its domain name. How can I easily and quickly update all my bookmarks to point to the new domain?

I really don't want to take the time to manually change each bookmark individually, though I guess I could if there's no easy way to do this.

I'm using Windows 7, and my browser of choice is Chrome, but I can use any browser and 'port the bookmarks back and forth if a different one makes it easier.

Comment: How you do this depends on the browser.  IE just uses shortcuts.  Firefox and Chrome store bookmarks differently.  Unless this domain is being sold, the current bookmarks, should continue to work.  Why do you have multiple bookmarks to the same site?

Comment: The bookmarks are to separate pages on the site. The site is changing its hosting (hence the domain change), but keeping the path structure for all its pages. I have multiple bookmarks to get directly to different pages without having to go through the navigation or search system each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to do what you're asking is to:

1. Export your favorites to a text-based bookmarks.html file
2. Use a text editor and do a "search and replace" for the
   domain names
3. Import the modified favorites file

The folks at google don't make the import/export options very accessible
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en

Using NotePad that comes with windows, you can use CTRL-H to bring up the "search and replace" menu.

Comment: Will the import for step 3 update the existing bookmarks or add new ones? In other words, can I leave the current ones there, or should I delete them before I run the import?

Comment: Ya, know... I'm not really sure.  I'd recommend that you try it with 1 or 2 favorites first (by editing the HTML file and removing all but 1 or 2 entries).  Sorry, I'm not at a PC with Chrome right now.... or I'd try it myself

Comment: I tried it, and Chrome adds the imported bookmarks into a subfolder. I had to manually reorganize my bookmarks by moving the new ones and deleting the old ones, but at least they were all updated correctly and in the same order within the folders. I also discovered that Chrome allows separate folders with duplicate names as subfolders to the same parent folder.